# Power BI - display multiple columns in one and perform count

Tags: powerbi

I have imported an excel into PowerBI. The format of the Excel is like

ItemName, Type, Item1, Item1Status, Item2, Item2Status, Item3, Item3Status...

Item1, Item2 & Item3 are really same data types - converted 1-to-many relationships to display in excel.

Item1Status, Item2Status & Item3Status are same data types - converted 1-to-many relationships to display in excel.

I want to create a visual representation in the format

Item, ItemStatus Count, where Type="some type"

How can I do this?

Comment: From the description it seems your data is not normalized but pivoted. Normalize your data into a flat table.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this in the Edit Queries window.

First I would select all the Item1, Item2 ... columns and choose Transform / Unpivot columns.  Then I would rename the resulting Attribute column to "Item Column" and rename the Value column to "Item".

Then I would repeat the Unpivot for the Item1Status, Item2Status ... columns. Then I would rename the resulting Attribute column to "ItemStatus Column" and rename the Value column to "ItemStatus".

Next I would Add a Custom Column, and write a formula like this:

```
= [Item Column] = Text.Start ( [ItemStatus Column] , 5 )
```

Filter the result to keep only the TRUE rows, and remove all the "working out" columns.

Comment: I have tried this. The first time I un-pivot it shows "Error" on individual cells. On clicking the cell - it shows the message - DataFormat.Error: Invalid cell value '#REF!'. After this, I cannot further unpivot the table.

Comment: It sounds like you have trashy data in excel - typical. I would try to use Replace Values to clean that (e.g. replace #REF! with null) before the unpivot.